# Hoffman and Kunze. Linear Algebra. Chapter 3, Section 3.5, Exercise 6.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers and $F$ a field. Let $f_1,\cdots,f_m$ be linear functionals on $F^n$. For $\alpha$ in $F^n$ define
>   \begin{equation}T\alpha=(f_1(\alpha),\cdots,f_m(\alpha)).\end{equation}
>   Show that $T$ is a linear transformation from $F^n$ into $F^m$. Then show that every linear transformation from $F^n$ into $F^m$ is of the above form, for some $f_1,\cdots,f_m$.

I did understand the question but can't start the solution. Thank you

Comment: Do you know what a "linear transformation" is?  A function, L, from a vector space to a vector space is a "linear transformation" if, for vectors u and v and numbers a and b, L(au+ bv)= aL(u)+ bL(v).  Show that is true for the given function.

Answer (score 2):

The first part isn't difficult since $$ T(v + \alpha w) = (f_{1}(v + \alpha w), ..., f_{m}(v + \alpha w))$$ thus the conclusion is just an application of the definitions. For the second part, you could observe that, given $T: F^{n} \to F^{m}$ a linear transformation and $v \in F^{n}$
$$T(v) = (\alpha_{1}, ..., \alpha_{m})$$
ie, you have well defined the maps 
$$f_{j}: v\in F^{n} \mapsto \alpha_{j}\in F, $$
for all $j = 1, ..., m$ and your result is proved if you show that these $f_{j}$ are linear functionals. Can you conclude from here?